# Make Git repository from two different folder locations?

Tags: git

I have two different folders located not under the same parent folder.

Is it possible to make a Git repository that includes them both rather than I having to make two Git repositories one for each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move these directories to a single parent, create a git repo, and create symlinks to the directories in previous paths.

In a similar situation I also created a script to make these symlinks automatically (I had much more of them than 2) and added it to the repo.

Comment: Can't I just create a folder, then add symlinks to those folders and create a git repo?

Comment: No, because git treats symlinks as symlinks and will not track the contents of the directories they point to.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by having a folder with [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to the two directories, thereby giving them a common parent folder.

Comment: Quoted from a source: "You cannot create a hardlink for a directory."

Comment: @weng: that depends on the OS/Filesystem. On Windows, NTFS Junction points are basically hardlinks to directories: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point